# Automised way to activate Receive Billing Alerts Option with the AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm looking for an automised way to activate the option the AWS Billing Preferences to receive billing alerts. As far as know, this is a requirement for receiving billing alerts from Cloudwatch.

I searched the boto3 reference doc, but I wasn't successfull. I don't want to use static checkt like mentionend [here](https://medium.com/@rafael.natali/lambda-python-for-daily-aws-billing-alert-52559aac7552).

For me, some scanning over a certain preiod and threshold seems to be the ideal solution.

I'm thinking of a [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in an account set up stack to activate this option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at AWS budgets? it might solve your need, You can set it to many dimensions and thresholds

Comment: Yeah I know about budgets, but the stackholder requires a global alarm on all AWS spendings.

Comment: Are you using AWS consolidated account? Organization?

Comment: Yes. I need to clarify, that the Billing Alert needs to be placed on the OUs as well as on a specific account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dvir669. I figured out, that [AWS Budgets](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-budgets/?nc1=h_ls) solves my problems without restrictions according to regions (global service, with regional endpoints) and without the need to change billing preferences. But `AWS Budgets` comes with a sophisticated billing dashboard. Finally, the alert notifications are well-formatted and by default no SNS topic is needed. I attached a picture.

[image]

Within the CDK, it's pretty simple to configure AWS Budgets:

```
# CDK Libs
from aws_cdk import core
from aws_cdk import aws_budgets as _budgets

class BillingAlertStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here

        #####################
        # Emails for Alerts
        #####################

        emails_list = [
            "youremail1@example.com",
            ...
        ]

        #####################
        # Thresholds for Alerts
        #####################

        thresholds_list = [
            15,
            ...
        ]

        #####################
        # Budget Alert
        #####################

        subscribers_list=[]

        for emails in emails_list:
            subscribers_list.append(
                _budgets.CfnBudget.SubscriberProperty(
                    address=emails,
                    subscription_type="EMAIL"
                )
            )

        for thresholds in thresholds_list:
            property= _budgets.CfnBudget.BudgetDataProperty(
                budget_type="COST",
                budget_limit=_budgets.CfnBudget.SpendProperty(
                    amount=thresholds,
                    unit="USD"
                ),
                time_unit="MONTHLY",
            )
            budgets = _budgets.CfnBudget(
                self,
                id="Budget-{}".format(thresholds),
                budget=property,
                notifications_with_subscribers=[
                    _budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationWithSubscribersProperty(
                        notification=_budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationProperty(
                            comparison_operator="GREATER_THAN",
                            notification_type="ACTUAL",
                            threshold=80,
                            threshold_type="PERCENTAGE"
                        ),
                        subscribers=subscribers_list
                    )
                ]
            )
```

As you can see,  so far no elaborated constructs are available, but `Python` it self brings advantages against plain `CloudFormation`. Within the `app.py`, you can specifiy multiple accounts at once. Which makes perfectly sense, to apply AWS Budgets on an OU within `AWS Organizations`.